# How to substring a parameter with html

Tags: xml, xslt, substring

I have a template that parses an html string. I don't know if I need to pass the parameter with disable-output-escaping="yes" or no and I don't know how to substring it afterwards!
I understand that "no" means >< and "yes" means >< .
The $dd =

```
  <a onclick="OpenPopUpPage('http:mysite', RefreshPage); return false;" href="http://mysite/showpage.html&ID=346&RootFolder=*">21/3/2014</a>
```

and I need to have as a substring only the :21/3/2014

The code is :

```
<xsl:variable name="dd">
<xsl:value-of select="string($thisNode/@RelatedMeeting)" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:call-template name="getDate">
          <xsl:with-param name ="date1" select="$dd"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and :

```
<xsl:template name="getDate">
   <xsl:param name ="date1"/> <-- This should be : 21/3/2014</a>
       <xsl:variable name="dateString2">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($date1,'>')"/> <----- here I have a problem,
    </xsl:variable>
<!-- .... more code here -->
</xsl:template>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($date1, '&gt;'), '&lt;')"/>`.

Comment: Thank you
Should disable-output-escaping be yes or no?

Comment: Forget about `disable-output-escaping`, it is a final serialization feature that is never applied when you construct the contents of a variable as no serialization happens at that stage of a transformation.

Comment: it didn't worked inside the template (!), so I moved it outside:     <xsl:variable name="dd">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(string($thisNode/@RelatedMeeting),'&gt;'),'&lt;')"/>

    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:call-template name="getDate">
      <xsl:with-param name ="date1" select="$dd"/>
    </xsl:call-template>